# Python.h missing from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04

I installed an openflow controller on my Ubuntu 12.04 called RYU using:

```
 sudo  pip install ryu
```

I was trying to run a python file using ryu-manager as shown below.

```
sudo ryu-manager simple_switch.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ryu-manager", line 19, in <module>
    import gevent
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

Then I tried to install gevent using:

```
sudo pip install gevent
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/core.o
gevent/core.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What is the cause of this error? I tried to locate `Python.h` using `sudo locate Python.h`, but without success. The output of `python -V` however is

```
Python 2.7.3
```

Should `Python.h` be there on the system? If so, what should I install to get it?

Comment: Location of header files is related to programming, voting for reopen.

Comment: Hit this issue when trying to run my Django code under NGINX.   That definitely programming related.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This should do it:

`sudo apt-get  update; sudo apt-get install  python-dev -y`

It will install any missing headers. It helped me a lot.

Comment: If you are using another version of Python, 3.3 for example: sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, the command 'sudo apt-get install python3' installed the right version without having to specify the version the command line.

Comment: Hitting the same issue on Centos7.3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 36):

Even if you have Python installed, the header file and the library usually aren't installed by default. On Ubuntu, they come in a separate package called [`python-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev).

Answer (score 9):

Install `gevent` directly - `sudo apt-get install python-gevent`.

Answer (score 0):

hey community i solved this problem by this command

> pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue

hope it works :)