# Having trouble installing PyAudio for Python3 on Mint

Tags: python, unix, linux-mint, portaudio, pyaudio

I was following the instructions [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html) and I'm having trouble getting the installation to work.  Basically, the first part works fine.  I downloaded portaudio, followed the instructions, and it all seemed to work.

However, when I tried`python3 setup.py install`, I got an error.  The error came from the /src/_portaudiomodule.c file, and it said that "The file Python.h could not be found".  I don't really understand what's going on because there was no Python.h file when I extracted the PyAudio archive.  I don't know where the Python.h file was supposed to come from.

I'm kind of a noob to unix systems so I could have easily made a mistake somewhere.  I've been trying to solve this for hours and I've had no luck so far.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe `apt-get install python-dev`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python.h missing from Ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631135/python-h-missing-from-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 5):

To install the latest version of pyaudio using conda:

```
source activate -your environment name-

pip install pyaudio
```

You may run into the following error when installing from pip:

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
 #include "portaudio.h" 
 compilation terminated.
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

That is because you don't have the PortAudio development package installed. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the portaudio19-dev installation tip, I was stuck at the portaudio.h error!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to compile pyaudio. To [install PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads), run:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
```

The first command [enables Universe Ubuntu repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/3712).

If you want to compile it e.g., to use the latest version from git; install build dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
```

After that, you could install it from sources using `pip`:

```
$ python3 -mpip install pyaudio
```

Or to install the current version from git:

```
$ pip install -e git+http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git#egg=pyaudio
```

Run `pip` commands inside a virtualenv or add `--user` command-line option, to avoid modifying the global `python3` installation (leave it to the package manager).

I've tested it on Ubuntu. Let me know if it fails on Mint.

Comment: I wasn't able to get those commands working on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the wheel was failing to build.

Comment: @wordsforthewise: I've just tested it: all commands work. Did you run the `build-dep` command before trying to compile pyaudio?

Comment: That was giving me an error, add urls to sources.list file, so I added the urls and now the build-dep worked.  I already have it installed now though, so I dunno but it would probably work.

Comment: @wordsforthewise I've added the explicit command to enable the Universe Ubuntu repository that contains python{,3}-pyaudio Ubuntu packages if you need it (no need to edit `sources.list` manually).

Comment: In case anyone came here trying to install this on OSX, I had to first run `brew install portaudio` then I ran `pip3 install pyaudio` with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the work arround for mac.

please refer the below steps to install pyaudio on python 3.5

Follow these steps :

- export HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1
- xcode-select --install
- brew update
- brew upgrade
- brew install portaudio
- pip install pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it install with [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), using [this package](https://anaconda.org/bokeh/pyaudio).

Follow install instructions for linux [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix), then do:

```
conda install -c bokeh pyaudio=0.2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install using the the below command

```
pip install pyaudio
```

after that install the required  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0
refer the below image for the same.

[image]

and restart the system and run the same command again

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Python.h is nothing but a header file. It is used by gcc to build applications. You need to install a package called python-dev. This package includes header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications. To install this package, enter:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```